# How to disable warning: null character(s) preserved in literal?

Tags: gcc, suppress-warnings

Basically I want to ignore warnings about null-chars in literals.

GCC says that this warning is enabled by default.

I can't find an appropriate `-Wno-` option for this warning.

You get such warnings in code like this

```
const char input[] = "abc^@123";
```

where `^@` denotes the ASCII 0 character (you can enter it with `vim` via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> - and verify it via <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> in command mode while the cursor is placed over the character).

Comment: Any reason for not using `\0` instead?

Comment: Ok. With `-std=gnu99`, you can use raw strings and the warning does not trigger in that case. But that might not be feasible.

Comment: @Mat, I tested it and it seems that you have to escape it like `\000` - `\0` does not work - but with `\000` I don't get the warnings. Not needing to escape would be a little bit more convenient, though - e.g. being able to copy/paste protocol captures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening in the lexer, and it doesn't look like you can disable the check. :-(  Here's the code snippet from `libcpp/lex.c`:

```
if (saw_NUL && !pfile->state.skipping)
  cpp_error (pfile, CPP_DL_WARNING,
         "null character(s) preserved in literal");
```

As you can see, there's no check of any options before emitting the warning.